# how to derive a class (from e.g. Eigen::VectorXf) with (only) an extra static method while retaining all the base constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, eigen, static-methods, derived-class

Let's say I need to attach some 'type id' to my `Eigen::VectorXf` vectors.

So far I have something like this (simplified for brevity):

```
struct MyVector123 
{
    Eigen::VectorXf vec;
    static int id() {return 123};
};

struct MyVector456
{
    Eigen::VectorXf vec;
    static int id() {return 456};
};
```

(Please don't argue with me it's a poor design and I should not do this. You might be very right, but the legacy code I'm using requires me to do so...)

This is working fine but forces me to use `.vec` everywhere. I was wondering if I could do slightly better by deriving from `Eigen::VectorXf` directly, something like:

```
struct MyVector123 : public Eigen::VectorXf
{
    static int id() {return 123};
};

struct MyVector456 : public Eigen::VectorXf
{
    static int id() {return 456};
};
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to allow me to recycle all the base constructors, e.g. `MyVector123 x = MyVector123::Random(10)` generates a compile error:

> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Am I missing something simple to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inherit the constructor (c++ 11)

```
struct MyVector123 : public Eigen::VectorXf
{
    using Eigen::VectorXf::VectorXf;
    static int id() {return 123};
};
```